# "Cannot GET" ao fazer deploy no heroku

Tags: angularjs

Olá, alguém já passou por algo parecido que possa me ajudar?

Ao colocar meu projeto em funcionamento no heroku, algumas funcionalidades relacionadas com o "v1/fotos" não funcionam e o console me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) fotos-controller.js:12 Objectconfig: Objectdata: "Cannot
>   GET /v1/fotos↵"headers: (c)status: 404statusText: "Not
>   Found"**proto**: Object

Segue o link do heroku: https://bancodeimagens.herokuapp.com/

Link do github: https://github.com/ThallysonB/Banco-de-Imagens

Answer (score 0):

O Heroku não aceita escrita, somente leitura. No caso de upload de imagens, ela até pode ficar salva em alguns minutos, mas porém ela será deletada automaticamente em algum momento.

A imagem só ficará disponível para acessá-la se ela existir em seu projeto quando você estiver realizando o deploy de seu projeto.

Para solucionar isto, você pode direcionar o upload de imagem para um serviço na web, e não deixá-las em sua instância node.js. Um bom serviço que salva suas imagens na nuvem é o **[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)**.